# ElectronJS findInPage find next result and highlight it

Tags: javascript, electron

I have electron app (^19.0.1) that opens website via url in BrowserWindow. I need to create text search functionality like standard Chrome searchbar.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

At this moment i can find and mark searchable text via `webContents.findInPage`, but i couldn't jump to next result, what i'm doing wrong?

My main.js:

```js
win.webContents.on('found-in-page', (event, result) => {
    console.log(result)
});


ipcMain.on('search-text', (event, arg) => {
    let nextRes = arg.direction == 'next' ? true : false
    const requestId = win.webContents.findInPage(arg.searchText, {
        forward: true,
        findNext: nextRes,
        matchCase: false
    });
});

ipcMain.on('stop-search', (event, arg) => {
    win.webContents.stopFindInPage('clearSelection');
});
```

My preload.js:

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
    searchText: (searchText, direction) => ipcRenderer.send('search-text', { searchText, direction }),
    stopSearch: () => ipcRenderer.send('stop-search')
})

function search(direction) {
    let searched = document.getElementById("searchInput").value.trim();
    if(searched.length > 0){
        window.electronAPI.searchText(searched,direction)
    }                
    document.getElementById("searchInput").focus()
}
```

Comment: if `findNext` is true, the search will start over from the beginning - is this what you intended?

Comment: Unfortunately no, when i want to search next i run find In Page with parameter findNext = true, but nothing happens

Comment: It only increase requestId parameter? by all other is still same

 `{
  requestId: 9,
  matches: 3,
  selectionArea: { x: 230, y: 157, width: 46, height: 17 },
  activeMatchOrdinal: 1,
  finalUpdate: true
`

Comment: After several unsuccessful attempts i found something. if i won't use ipcMain and for example i`ll put this function in setInterval it works well